# trying to draw a hexagon shape in

Tags: java, graphics, polygon, polygons

I'm trying to draw a hexagon shaped asteroid on a clone of Asteroids I'm making for a class.

```
    sprite = new Polygon();
    sprite.addPoint(0,0);
    sprite.addPoint(0,-40);
    sprite.addPoint(30,-40);
    sprite.addPoint(60,-10);
    sprite.addPoint(60,20);
    sprite.addPoint(40,50);
    sprite.addPoint(-20,50);
    sprite.addPoint(-50,20);
    sprite.addPoint(50,-10);
    sprite.addPoint(20,-40);
```

Yet when I do it, I end up with this
[image: :]

So what is going wrong?  I drew it out on a coordinate plane, and copied the points over. It was my understanding that Java would draw it out in the order I listed the points, and I had the (0,0) in there in the interest of rotating the asteroid for the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really a hexagon, the last two points look strange

```
sprite.addPoint(50,-10);
sprite.addPoint(20,-40);
```

Think those final two should be:

```
sprite.addPoint(-50,-10);
sprite.addPoint(-20,-40);
```

but even with that, its going to look a lop-sided pacman - back to the drawing board I think.

Answer (score 11):

Zane is close, he forgot to include i in his formula:

```
for(i=0; i<6; i++) {
    sprite.addpoint(x + r*cos(i*2*pi/6), y + r*sin(i*2*pi/6))
}
```

Answer (score 6):

First, if it is supposed to be a hexagon, then it should have 6 points, not 10. Second, just drawing this on paper from your coordinates gives me quite a similar polygon as they one in your picture. So I guess your coordinates are wrong. Check them again.

If you want to draw a symmetric hexagon, then all you need is its center, say (x,y) and its radius r. Then the points of the hexagon are

```
for(i=0; i<6; i++) {
   sprite.addpoint(x + r*cos(i*2*pi/6), y + r*sin(i*2*pi/6))
}
```

Comment: Corrected this to match @Loran since this will only serve to throw people off otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I would check your coordinates. The last few transitions do not look right to me, especially (-50, 20) to (50, -10). It has a jump of 100 units in the x direction, bigger than any other change in coordinates. (-50, -10) seems more plausible.